# Getting Table to Filter based on choices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Created this in React--I'm having a hard time getting it to filter the search and display results.

I want to have the option to search by Title, Artist, Album, Release Date, Genre, and Likes,

I have tried putting the input bar in different locations

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

```js
// please add sample data here and remove this comment
const parentSongs = [
  {
    title: "a",
    artist: "a",
    album: "a",
    release_date: "a",
    genre: "a",
    likes: "a",
  },
  {
    title: "b",
    artist: "b",
    album: "b",
    release_date: "b",
    genre: "b",
    likes: "b",
  },
  {
    title: "c",
    artist: "c",
    album: "c",
    release_date: "c",
    genre: "c",
    likes: "c",
  },
];

const DisplayMusic = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");

  let songList = props.parentSongs.filter(function (el) {
    if (
      el.album.includes(search) &&
      el.artist.includes(search) &&
      el.genre.includes(search) &&
      el.release_date.includes(search) &&
      el.title.includes(search)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return (
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <input
          className="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={(event) => setSearch(event.target.value)}
        />
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
          <th>Album</th>
          <th>Release Date</th>
          <th>Genre</th>
          <th>Likes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {songList.map((song) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <tr key={song.id}>
                <td>{song.title}</td>
                <td>{song.artist}</td>
                <td>{song.album}</td>
                <td>{song.release_date}</td>
                <td>{song.genre}</td>
                <td>{song.likes}</td>
              </tr>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<DisplayMusic parentSongs={parentSongs}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You probably want to use OR `||` instead of AND `&&` because certainly the song's artist, title, release date etc. won't all contain the same substrings and you only include a song in the result if it all those conditions contain the `search` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the conditions on filter. As @Mushroomator mentioned change it `||` instead of `&&`

```
let songList = props.parentSongs.filter(function (el) {
  if (
    el.album.includes(search) ||
    el.artist.includes(search) ||
    el.genre.includes(search) ||
    el.release_date.includes(search) ||
    el.title.includes(search)
  ) {
    return true;
  }
});

// or simply (considering checking all the properties on song object)

let songList = props.parentSongs.filter((song) =>
  Object.values(song).some((item) => item.includes(search))
);
```

```js
const DisplayMusic = (props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");

  let songList = props.parentSongs.filter(function (el) {
    if (
      el.album.includes(search) ||
      el.artist.includes(search) ||
      el.genre.includes(search) ||
      el.release_date.includes(search) ||
      el.title.includes(search)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="search"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={(event) => setSearch(event.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Artist</th>
              <th>Album</th>
              <th>Release Date</th>
              <th>Genre</th>
              <th>Likes</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {songList.map((song) => {
              return (
                <tr key={song.id}>
                  <td>{song.title}</td>
                  <td>{song.artist}</td>
                  <td>{song.album}</td>
                  <td>{song.release_date}</td>
                  <td>{song.genre}</td>
                  <td>{song.likes}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const data = [
  {
    title: "a",
    artist: "a",
    album: "a",
    release_date: "a",
    genre: "a",
    likes: "a",
  },
  {
    title: "b",
    artist: "b",
    album: "b",
    release_date: "b",
    genre: "b",
    likes: "b",
  },
  {
    title: "c",
    artist: "c",
    album: "c",
    release_date: "c",
    genre: "c",
    likes: "c",
  },
];


ReactDOM.render(
  <DisplayMusic parentSongs={data} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Either option isn't showing results on the table. If I go to type anything in the input it's simply clearing out the entire table.  I believe the issue is actually getting the table to filter what is typed there to show the list of songs

Comment: @CodingNewb, Can you add the sample data you are using?

Comment: @CodingNewb I've edited your code to use a snippet. So once you add the sample data and pass it to the `<DisplayMusic/>` property we should be able to execute the snippet and so we actually see the results within the snippet immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry I am relatively new, what sample data would you be requiring? The array list?

Comment: No worries. I've now added some very simple sample data myself (and done some adjustments to make [React executable in a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)), but you can certainly replace it with some of your sample data. Using `||` instead of `&&` should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Mushroomator. @CodingNewb, Check the updated answer with working snippet. One more problem is having the `input` field in table header. I have moved up.